# ASP.NET AsyncFileUpload - Internet-Explorer Access is denied

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, asyncfileupload

I have an asp.net AsynFileUpload control on the page and an html image tag that fires the AsyncFileUpload click event.  Works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but not IE.

**Example**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetFile() {
            document.getElementById("<%=AsyncFileUpload1.ClientID %>").click();            
    }
</script>

<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="AsyncFileUpload1" />

<img id="flImage1" src="images/upload.png"  onclick="GetFile()" />
```

The uploader works fine in IE if I just use the uploader control.  But I need an image on the page that will fire the uploader control click event.

When I click the image that fires the JavaScript GetFile() function, it then calls the click event for the AsynFileUpload control.  I can then select my file for upload.  Once I select the file I get a JavaScript alert "Access is denied".

Anyone know what the issue is and how to get around it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= this.AsyncUpload.ClientID %>' + '_ctl02').click();
```